# mongoose .pre hook for update but it shows there's nothing like that

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here after lots of stuggle i'm finally able to check the `name exist` but now if person is editing some existing doc and edited name it should check in db for exiting name throw error that name exist.

here is logic for save and I want same logic at updating the document. 
Note: I am using react in front end, and this code is added on the API service call

```
company_model.companySchema.pre('save', function (next) {
                                try {
                                    cModel.find({ name: this.name }, function (err, docs) {
                                        try {
                                            if (!docs.length) {
                                                next();
                                            } else {
                                                console.log('company name exists: ', this.name);
                                                next(new Error("Company Name exists!"));
                                            }
                                        } catch (e) {
                                            console.error('error in cModel.find: ' + e.message)
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (e) {
                                    console.error('error in pre save : ' + e.message)
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: `try..catch` does not work with callbacks. It's really unclear what your question is. Is there a problem with the code above? ( other than the `try..catch` not working as mentioned ) Or are you asking how to implement something else? Its often better if you don't really understand exactly how to express something or even code for a particular task, that you instead **show** what you want to achieve instead. Possibly a small data sample, and the expected result of the operation you want to perform. Then people clearly understand you.

Comment: the above code is for `save` that works, but I want code for update using `.pre()`